# Fastlane, Pilot - Automatic Team Selection

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, fastlane

I m using pilot via fastfile:

```
  desc "Build and upload a new build to Apple TestFlight"
  lane :betaTest do
      testflight
  end
```

But It's asked me to choose the team every time

```
Multiple teams found, please enter the number of the team you want to use: 
1) "Team 1" (000000) 
2) "Team 2" (111111)
```

I tried to use `testfligh` like bellow, but it gives me an error:

```
testflight(
          username: "raed@gmail.com",
          team_id: "XXXXXX"
      )
```

Error:

```
[20:16:59]: Variable Dump:
[20:16:59]: {:DEFAULT_PLATFORM=>:ios, :PLATFORM_NAME=>:ios, :LANE_NAME=>"ios betaTest"}
[20:16:59]: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

    +------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
    |                     fastlane summary                     |
    +------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
    | Step | Action                              | Time (in s) |
    +------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
    | 1    | Verifying required fastlane version | 0           |
    | 2    | default_platform                    | 0           |
    | 3    | testflight                          | 15          |
    +------+-------------------------------------+-------------+

    [20:16:59]: fastlane finished with errors
    Successfully submitted a crash report. If this is a problem with one of the tools specifically,
    please submit an issue on GitHub and attach the following number to it: '4431202597d937abb0026b96ff88698d'
    The crash report has been stored locally '/tmp/sentry_4431202597d937abb0026b96ff88698d.json'
    /Users/raed.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': [!] getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
```

Is there a way to automate the selection of the team id?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should also specify the `itc_team_id` in your `Appfile`.

```
# To select a team for iTunes Connect use
itc_team_name "YOUR TEAM NAME"
itc_team_id "iTunes Connect Team ID"
```

Comment: how I can find the itunes connect team ID because I found that is not same with team id in apple Developer Account ?